# Is there a way to replace text by a styled text using google doc API?

Tags: google-api, google-docs-api

[ReplaceAllTextRequest] doc[1](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.docs.v1/ReplaceAllTextRequest-class.html)

It seems I could only replace a plain text by another plain text?

Can I add format into the replacement? e.g. make the replacement red+bold

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the text style cannot be modified using "ReplaceAllTextRequest" while the texts are replaced. So as one of workarounds, at first, it replaces the texts using "ReplaceAllTextRequest". And it retrieves the indexes of the replaced values using documents.get, and then, modify the text style using "UpdateTextStyleRequest". Because "ReplaceAllTextRequest" doesn't return the indexes of replaced texts. By the way, Docs API is growing now. So your goal might be able to be directly achieved by the future update. If my comment was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: That's my impression after reading the docs. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you could obtain your direction for achieving your goal, how about posting it as an answer? By this, I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same question.

Comment: Oh I didn't do it the other way. I was hoping to use it to merge a csv with 20+ fields into a template. I expect the aforementioned method will drive the users crazy

Comment: and i don't know any more elegant solutions unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no current way of replacing text by styled text using the Docs API at the current moment.

As a workaround, you can:

1. [GET](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) all the contents of the document.
2. Find the ranges of the document that will be replaced (find text-to-replace matches). Re-calculate the ranges that the replaced text will have after issuing the [`ReplaceAllTextRequest`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#ReplaceAllTextRequest) request.
3. Issue the [`ReplaceAllTextRequest`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#ReplaceAllTextRequest) request.
4. Using the ranges calculated at step 2, issue all the appropriate [`UpdateTextStyleRequest`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetextstylerequest) requests. All this requests can be sent as a single [`batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) request.